# Find total yards with LXWXH?

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

I have a box I need to cover all 6 sides with a single layer fiberglass fabric. The fabric comes in 50" or 28" widths.  The dimensions of the box are 34" long; 15" wide; 12" High. How do I determine how many total yards I need to buy depending on the the width I choose?

Comment: A box has six sides. Draw the picture, and then find the area of each of the six sides and add the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box is a rectangular prism, so there are three pairs of identical sides. So, we can calculate the surface area of each of the unique sides, sum these, then multiply by $2$.

The first unique side is: $34'' \times 15'' = 510$ square inches.

The second: $34'' \times 12'' = 408$ square inches.

The third: $15'' \times 12'' = 180$ square inches.

Sum these and multiply by $2$, and we have $2196$ square inches.

As for how many of a certain sheet it'll take, that depends on the length of the fabric sheets. We can just generalize and say they're $28 \times x$ and $50 \times x$ square inch sheets. So, they area of a sheet would be $28x$ and $50x$, respectively. To determine how many of either sheet you'd need, you just compute $2196/28x$ and $2196/50x$ for each size of sheet.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help!